# how to fix gradle daemon running for very long time?

Tags: android, gradle

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tz11l.png)

I am facing this problem from past few days. Some times it is working normally but it has been more than 1 hr but not able to start coding.

Comment: happens sometimes... restart androidstudio to fix it.

Comment: it take sometime due to slow internet, ok kill studio and start again

Answer (score -2):

Android Studio

In Android Studio you can make gradle to build your apps fully offline by activating this option:

```
Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build tools -> Gradle
```

[image]